# Download images BEFORE uitableviewcell is displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

As you can imagine these keywords (download image uitableviewcell) will return results related to problems of "lazy loading" which is not what I want to know.

What I want to know is if there is a way to download the images before the cell is displayed.

Would be great if we could download the images for the visible cells plus 5 or 6 in advance, and continue to download 5/6 images in advance, while the table runs

of course all the links are stored in one array, so it's easy to get them in advance

I'm using AFNetworking for all the network operations

Thanks

Comment: Does the server responds with a caching policy for the images?

Comment: the images are few kb, the biggest doesn't exceed 200 kb!

Comment: UITableViewCells can scroll by pretty quickly, not a lot of time to preload. Maybe set up a queue to start loading images and see how far you get before they're needed.

Comment: I would recommend checking out https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage, it pretty gracefully handles asynchronous loading of images in tableviews

Answer (score 0):

**Naive solution**

If your images have a caching policy then you can prefetch as many as you like and on the next actual call where you load the image in the cell it will load it faster (from the cache). This is a bit naive, since you base everything on the predicate that the server uses caching mechanisms on the client side to reduce the number of network operations (but this is not always the case).

**Better Solution**

Also, you can implement your own data structure (for example extend NSMutableDictionary) to store, handle the images and download the images whenever you want. For example when you load the table view you can start downloading the images that are going to be displayed plus a few more images for the next cells. However, as @picciano said the scrolling of a table view can be pretty quick so, prefetching is just a waste of your time.

**Comment**

This kind of prefetching makes sense only when the user is connected to a high speed network. But in case the user is connected to a slow network, then you will create a big chunk of network operations which will take time to complete (not very battery efficient).